# How to open a jupyter notebook in read only mode?

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there a way to view a jupyter notebook in read only mode?

I'm trying to use a git repo to share notebooks and collaborate on analysis. The problem is the moment I open a co-workers notebook to review their work, the metatdata seems to be updated, causing an apparent diff to git. So, if I git pull to get an update to that notebook, I get a conflict.

The simplest option to avoid this would be to just "view" the notebook, rather than open it for editing. I'm wondering if there is a plugin or something that lets me do this.

Comment: You can use [nbpreview](https://jsvine.github.io/nbpreview/). As described at the very top [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71094775/8508004), it is secure because it is actually running inside your browser to render the view of the underlying json composing the saved notebook data. Nothing leaves your computer. See more about it at [the nbpreview repo](https://github.com/jsvine/nbpreview).